# AlpineJs x-model value set not working to x-data out dive

Tags: javascript, datatables, alpine.js

Datatble Server Side Processing  is dynamically comming from backend yajra datatable

```
  <div x-data="AppData()">
   <form>
    <input x-model="user.name" />
    <input x-model="user.age" />
   </form>
</div>`

<table id="datatable">
 <tr>
   <td>Jhone<td>
   <td>27<td>
 <td><button onclick="AppData().getEdit({name:'Jhone',age:27})">Edit<button><td>
</tr>
```

`

//AlpineJs Code For X-Data

```
<script>
   function AppData()
   {
     return {
       user:{},
       getEdit(user)
       {
         this.user = user;        
       }
  };
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Link only questions or answers are prone to link rot and will not get you any answers, please refer to the FAQ on how to ask good questions and edit your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You bind the input elements to non-existing object attributes. You need to define them before you bind them to an element. Furthermore the `AppData().getEdit()` does not work and is unnecessary. You can just set the `user` object with the respective data.

```
<div x-data="AppData()">
  <form>
    <input x-model="user.name" />
    <input x-model="user.age" />
  </form>

  <table id="datatable">
    <tr>
      <td>Jhone</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td><button @click="user = {name: 'Jhone', age: '27'}">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<script>
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.data('AppData', () => ({
    user: {
      name: '',
      age: ''
    },
  }))
})
</script>
```

Note that I moved the table into the main div, where Alpine.js' `x-data` directive is present, so the code in `@click` can access the component data.